# Clarifying step in proof: sums of limit superiors

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I am learning about limits for the first time and while reading old questions on here, I stumbled upon this:
[Question about sums of limit superiors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798726/question-about-sums-of-limit-superiors?rq=1)

Could someone clarify a step for me?

We have set $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and got $s_n+t_n < \alpha + \beta + \epsilon$. So far everthing is clear to me. However, then they follow from this that:

$\sup \{s_n+t_n|n>N\} \leq \alpha + \beta + \epsilon$ and therefore $\limsup (s_n+t_n) \leq \alpha + \beta$.

I don't understand how we get from $s_n+t_n < \alpha + \beta + \epsilon$ to $\sup \{s_n+t_n|n>N\} \leq \alpha + \beta + \epsilon$ and why from this we can conclude the limit superior as smaller or equal to $\alpha + \beta$.

Comment: If all members of set $A$ are less than $b$ then $\sup A\leq b$. Do you get this?

Comment: Further if $a\leq b+\epsilon $ for all positive $\epsilon$ then $a\leq b $.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Just one quick question: why does it change from $<$ to $\leq$?

Comment: @golde suppose for example $s_n=t_n=-\frac{1}{2^n}$.  Then $s_n+t_n < 0$ for all $n$ but $\lim\sup s_n+t_n = 0$

Comment: More generally, the supremum and infimum of a set do not need to be in the set. But they must be in the closure of the set, since every neighborhood of them must contain elements of the set. So $$\{s_n+t_n|n>N\} \subseteq (-\infty, \alpha + \beta + \epsilon)$$ only implies that $$\sup \{s_n+t_n|n>N\} \in (-\infty, \alpha + \beta + \epsilon]$$